# Converting string to datetime results in incorrect hours/minutes/seconds

Tags: stata

### Objective

I am converting a vector of strings of the following format `"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS"` to a Stata recognizable datetime using the `clock()` function.

### The problem

The resulting converted datetime is not equivalent to the input. Here is the code that I've used,

```
gen datetime = clock(dt, "MDY hms")
format datetime %tc
```

and here is the resulting data, where the original string is `dt` and is a str19 type in %19s format and `datetime` is the converted variable as a float formatted as %tc,

| dt | datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2016 1:00:00 | 01jan2016 01:00:27 |
| 1/1/2016 2:00:00 | 01jan2016 01:59:25 |
| 1/1/2016 3:00:00 | 01jan2016 03:00:35 |
| 1/1/2016 4:00:00 | 01jan2016 03:59:34 |

### What I've done

I have read through the the Stata User Manual's [Chapter 24 Working with dates and times](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/u24.pdf) as well as [Datetime translation](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/ddatetimetranslation.pdf) and could not parse out any clues to what is happening, so any help is greatly appreciated.

### Sample Data

```
clear
input str19 dt
"1/1/2016 1:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 2:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 3:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 4:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 5:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 6:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 7:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 8:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 9:00:00" 
"1/1/2016 10:00:00"
end
```

Comment: You need to specify -double- as variable type. This is mentioned repeatedly in the documentation.

Comment: Beautiful, sorry I missed that. Thanks @NickCox

Comment: Credit for clearly stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `double` as variable type. This is mentioned repeatedly in the documentation.